# How to avoid using twice replace (using only one regex) in the following script?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to edit a string from:

`rgb(250, 0, 0) 10px 10px 50px 0px`

to:

`rgba(250, 0, 0, 1) 10px 10px 50px 0px`

Assuming the input value is always correct, I need to add alpha channel of 1.

The follow script I created works, but I was wondering about the double replace.

I would like to know if you perform a better way, maybe using only one `regex` and avoiding using `replace` twice or a better alternative.

```js
        var _convertBoxShadowToTgba = function (boxShadow) {
            return boxShadow.replace(/rgb/i, 'rgba').replace(/\)/i, ', 1)');
        };
        var original = "rgb(250, 0, 0) 10px 10px 50px 0px";
        var final = _convertBoxShadowToTgba(original);
        console.log('original', original);
        console.log('final', final);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
rgb(.*?\d)\)
```

Explanation:

```
rgb          # Match literal `rgb`
    (        # Start of capturing group (1)
        .*?  # Match every thing lazily
        \d   # Up to a digit
    )        # End of capturing group (1)
\)           # That is followed by a closing bracket
```

Replacement string:

```
rgba$1, 1)
```

*`$1` is a back-reference to first capturing group*

JS code:

```
original.replace(/rgb(.*?\d)\)/i, 'rgba$1, 1)')
```

[**Live demo**](https://www.regex101.com/r/hMcRW6/1)

Comment: The battle for rep on simple regexp questions is endless :)

Comment: When two answers are posted accidentally in a moment, improving one to promote a better understating of solution is better than removing it. @xShirase

Comment: @revo I totally agree, that is what makes SO great, the diversity of explanations and approaches. I often find valuable information within more than one answer. Congrats on a great post

Answer (score 0):

Use groups, like this :

```
/rgb(.*)\)/
```

this will group everything between rgb and the last parenthesis.
You can then reuse the group within your replace expression :

```
.replace(/rgb(.*)\)/, 'rgba$1, 1')
```

Test :

```
a = 'rgb(250, 0, 0) 10px 10px 50px 0px'

a.replace(/rgb(.*)\)/i, 'rgba$1, 1)')
>"rgba(250, 0, 0, 1) 10px 10px 50px 0px"
```

The way it works is as follows :

the expression between parenthesis is called a group, you can reuse it using $ variables in your replace expression.

For example :

```
a = 'Hello, foo!'
a.replace(/(Hello)(.*)(foo)/, '$3$2$1')
> foo, Hello!
```

In this example, groups are :

```
$1 : (Hello)
$2 : (.*)
$3 : (foo)
```

You can switch them around, replace them, etc, as you wish.

[Further reading on regex grouping](http://javascript.info/tutorial/groups)

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a function to the replace method.
Like this:

```
var _convertBoxShadowToTgba = function (boxShadow) {
        return boxShadow.replace(/rgb|\)/g, function($0) {
                 if ($0 == 'rgb') { return 'rgba';}
                 if($0 == ')') {return ', 1)';}
            });
 };
 var original = "rgb(250, 0, 0) 10px 10px 50px 0px";
 var final = _convertBoxShadowToTgba(original);
 console.log('original', original);
 console.log('final', final);
```